# I failed a phase challenge. Can I try it again?

Tags: torchlight-2

I got into the king goo challenge, got surrounded, forgot to check my health bar and quite obviously died. The phase portal's seemingly gone.

Is this it? Does my character have no more tries to get the phat loot?

Answer (score 2):

If you save and exit while in a phase beast challenge, then when you start up again, you'll be at the beginning of the challenge, *but still have all of the items you got from it before*.  Thus, you can farm a challenge repeatedly this way.  Make sure before you go in that you have plenty of inventory room, both yours and your pet's.

Note that this only works in single player, as you'll always restart in town while in multiplayer.  And once you leave the phase zone, the only way to try again is to reroll the map and find a phase beast again (which might not give you the same challenge).

Answer (score 1):

For that specific instance of a phase challenge?  Yes (I think if you choose to ressurect at the start of the area but I'm not sure?).  Additionally, you'll find other phase monsters in your journeys, and so additional phase challenges will present themselves.  I believe it will be possible to find the same event at a later opportunity.

Comment: Is that "Yes" as in "Yes, you can try again", or "Yes" as in "Yes, that's it, you have no more tries to get phat loot"? Judging by the rest of your answer I'm guessing the latter, but wouldn't mind some extra clarity!

Comment: Yeah that answer was confusing.  I had other thoughts while typing that but somehow they didn't all make it to my finger tips.  I hope that's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I am in my 2nd attempt at the tar king fight right now, so yes you can try the same one again.

Comment: Care to elaborate on how to reactivate the fight?

Comment: Maybe just reseeding the map is enough?

Answer (score 1):

- You can go at it again if you choose to resurrect at the entrance of the map when you die.
- If you choose to resurrect at town you can't go to the same challenge again, either find another in different map or re-roll the world and hunt the phase beast again.
- You can also choose to quit if you die, then when you resume, you'll load the autosave on entering the portal.
- If you want to retry the challenge for a better result but nothing is left to kill you, you might want to keep Cacklespit's 'reward' on hand. That's designed to kill any player.